# Redirect request to mounted engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have a Ruby on Rails application `MyApp` which mounts an engine `V1`:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  mount V1::Engine => '/v1'

  # More routes..
end
```

I need to redirect requests to the `V1` engine, ideally using path helpers like the ones supported when you use namespaces. E.g: `redirect_to v1_users_path`

`$> rake routes` in `MyApp` application shows:

```
# MyApp routes...

Routes for V1::Engine:

user_sign_in GET /user_sign_in(.:format) v1/users/sessions#new
user_log_out GET /user_log_out(.:format) v1/users/sessions#destroy
user_sessions POST /user_sessions(.:format) v1/users/sessions#create
users POST /users(.:format) v1/users#create
```

Comment: what does `rake routes` show?

Comment: @Yule I updated the question with the output of rake routes

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we use to redirect to an engine path:

```
redirect_to v1.users_path
```

Here v1 is the engine name.